# Unsupported or invalid SSH public key format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, aws-transfer-family

I have deployed a Transfer Family SFTP server (using an Amazon EFS). I am having trouble configuring the user. I keep getting the error: Failed to create user (Unsupported or invalid SSH public key format) when entering SSH public keys.

I have tried using the format according to AWS format [AWS-DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/key-management.html#sshkeygen)by using puTTY gen, but I still, get the error. Has anyone had this issue and how did you solve it?

Comment: Please Edit your question to show us how you have been generating and referencing the keys, so that we can attempt to reproduce your situation by following the same steps.

Comment: After some additional research, I discovered that the output from the puTTy format was incorrect. I should have modified the format to start with ssh- rsa. After modifying, the file in that format it now works!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If you don't think this question will help future readers, feel free to delete it. Or, feel free to add your own Answer with enough details to help future readers.

Comment: It works when you copy a public key from the puttygen's "Key" textarea. It does not work if you save a public key to a file and then copy the file's content into AWS.